# How notify sysadmin when happens an Internal Error?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I read some documentation and some examples about Logging in Flask. Then I write this piece of code:

```
ADMINS = [config["sys_admin_email"]]

if not app.debug:
    from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler

    mail_handler = SMTPHandler(mailhost=('smtp.email.com', 587),
                               credentials=('helpdesk@email.com', 'fsociety'),
                               fromaddr='helpdesk@email.com',
                               toaddrs=ADMINS, subject='Service Failed')
    mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    # config the format
    mail_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('''
        Message type:       %(levelname)s
        Location:           %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d
        Module:             %(module)s
        Function:           %(funcName)s
        Time:               %(asctime)s

        Message:

        %(message)s
        '''))
    app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```

But I can't understand how the mail_handler will handle with a exception ?
I ask that because I want to notify my sysadmin when an Internal Error (500) raises.

Note: Maybe I need a error handler so I created this method to catch all Internal Errors. But doesn't work.

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def reportToSysAdmin(e):
    app.logger.error(e)
    print "email sent"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the following link:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/

**Details:**

Above code created a new SMTPHandler that will send mails with the mail server listening on 127.0.0.1 to all the ADMINS from the address server-error@example.com with the subject “Service Failed”. If your mail server requires credentials, these can also be provided. For that check out the documentation for the SMTPHandler.